# Givien a pre-sorted array with distinct values, find i such that A[i]=i

Tags: algorithm, search, time-complexity

Question:

Let A be an array of size n of integers, where **`A[1] < A[2] < ... < A[n]`**.

(Note that each entry may be a positive or negative integer.)

1. Give an algorithm that takes `O(log n)` time to find an `i` such that `A[i] = i`, provided such an `i` exists. If no such `i` exists, the algorithm returns `0`.
2. Prove that any algorithm to solve this problem using comparisons must take time `Ω(log n)`.

So far I can only find an algorithm that takes `O(n)` time, which is easy, but I know that only a tree structure can be `O(log n)`.
I'm new to Algorithms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider there is some `i` where `a[i] > i` then for any `j > i` => `a[j] > j` from the statement `A[1] < A[2] < ... < A[n].`

Also for any `i` where `a[i] < i`, for any `j < i` => `a[j] < j` will hold for the same reason.

Thus, we can use Binary Search here. (For a selected point `p` if `a[p] > p` then continue with the left part and if `a[p] < p` then proceed to the right part)

Comment: @Yugandhar because it will take O(N) time, while we need O(logN) here